# I'm a transgender considering converting to Islam for boyfriend

Tags: conversion, relationships, transgender

My boyfriend is muslim. We dated for 2 years and I complete my post op about 3 months ago and am now a complete woman now. About 2 months ago he says he cannot be with me anymore because I'm not muslim. So now need to know how to convert fully to Islam. I was raised as a Baptist. Thank you.

Comment: Islam will be the best decision of your life, no doubt. But, accept it only as the path to know and please your creator, not for another person's sake. So, take your time to understand & ingest the basic ideas of Islam, first.

Answer (score 0):

First, congratulations on your surgery!

Technically, to become a Muslim you only need to sincerely believe in God (Allah, as the one true God) and his messenger, the Prophet Mohammad, and attest to this by saying the [shahada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada).  That's the easy part---you then need to become a good Muslim (establishing prayer, doing good deeds, reading the Qur'an, and so on), a considerable lifelong commitment.  Consequently, it is discouraged to rush into converting to Islam.

Some points that might be relevant to your situation:

- Islam is relatively accepting of transgender people.  However, while you will mostly be accepted as a woman in Islam, there are expectations on how to behave as a Muslim woman, and you won't be exempt from these; are you prepared to accept these?  Trans people tend to have feminist views, which can clash with the role of Muslim women in Islam.
- While there are gay Muslims, Islam tends to be unaccepting of gay people.  Even if you're not lesbian/bisexual/pansexual yourself, most trans people have gay friends.  How will converting to Islam affect your relationship with them?
- Did you know that Muslims don't traditionally have boyfriends/girlfriends?  So, after you convert to Islam, he still can't be your boyfriend (if he wants to be devout).  Would you be prepared to get married?  Are you aware of the role of a Muslim wife?
- Will you be prepared to observe veil (hijab)?  Note that it's a lot harder to be "passable" when hiding your lady bits.  (Facial feminization surgery can help with this.)
- Intersectionality.  You will face discrimination unique to transgender Muslims.  Islam is against altering God's creation, and thus some Muslims will use your surgery against you.  Some vocal Muslims believe that LGBT people should be executed, and members of the LGBT community will bring this up in conversation with you.

  [image: You're not welcome here.]

  (Original image source: unknown for sure; maybe [here](http://dontneedfeminism.deviantart.com/art/You-re-Not-Welcome-Here-536605948).)

I found http://newmuslims.com/ helpful as a new Muslim.

And, maybe you won't like it if I ask this, but just in case it's important...

- Your boyfriend broke up with you while you were 1-month post-op?  Is it possible that your boyfriend desires to be with a man, but was with you because Islam is against homosexuality?  And now you're post-op, he no longer wants you?  (Why now?  Why does he now care about being a devout Muslim when he didn't before?)
- Surgical painkillers are strong and can be hallucinogenic.  They take time to clear out of your system.  Are you sure you're thinking straight right now?